# Search from xml source file

Tags: c#, xml

I have csv data file with costumers (key) and they bill (value)

I need to run on this file and return costumer bill for every client that I want .
my question is what is the best way to work and search from file .

I can convert the file to json or xml file , I don't have to work with it as it , but I don't know what is the best to convert the file and what is the bast way to work with it that my search will be easy and fast.

can you please advice me the best way for it .

My program is a console application and im working with c#

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the xml? Are they elements / attributes etc ?

Comment: For now i have only csv file , so how can i convert it to xml ?

Comment: The first line of your question states 'I have xml data file' - where does it mention csv? Why convert it - just take the data from the csv file ...

Comment: Show us the csv and the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Linq to XML is probably the way to go ... something like

```
var bills = 
 (from data in xmlDocument.Descendants("Customers")
  select new {
    Name = data.Attribute("customer").Value,
    Value = data.Attribute("bill").Value,
  }).ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.Value);
```

would work - but without seeing your structure it's hard to guess.

Comment: and how can i convert csv file to xml?

Comment: You probably don't need to convert at all and just use the csv directly ... but we would need to see a snippet and what output you need to help